# Como puedo recorrer un JSON para guardar en mi base de datos

Tags: php, json, foreach

Quiero recorrer mi JSON para insertarlo pero a la hora de querer insertarlos me da error por que en los corchetes tengo numero[0] y ala hora de ya insertarlos no se como hacerle para ponerlo

```
array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
 var_dump($array);
 $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas(fecha, dinero) VALUES (DEFAULT, ? , ?)");
 $res = false;
 foreach ($array->{"data"} as $dineroS) {
    $ins->bindParam(1,$fecha);
    $ins->bindParam(2, $dineroS->{"  "}, PDO::PARAM_INT);//aca me da el error
    //$ins->bindParam(':Total', $total,PDO :: PARAM_STR);
    
}
```

Meda ese error si pongo dinero en las llavez

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, nos podrías mostrar como es el JSON y de que manera lo envías?

Comment: se va llenando conforme el usuario va ingresando los datos pueden ser 3 ,20,6 datos eso depende de cuantos se registren en el array en JavaScript  saco la suma de ese array y después convierto a JSON y lo mando a php que es el código que muestro, Ya lo logre que el array de tipo JSON lo reciba mi archivo php y lo muestra bien como se puede observar en las imágenes solo que me da error ala hora de insertar no se como hacerle.

Answer (score 1):

Segun el log la informacion que se esta procesando corresponde a:

```
{"data":[30,30]}
```

Ya que usas json_decode en modo objeto, el acceso es un poco distinto:

```
 $array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
 var_dump($array); // un objeto con atributo 'data'
 $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas(fecha, dinero) VALUES (? , ?)"); // solo 2 valores: fecha, dinero
 $res = false;
 foreach ($array->data as $index=>$value) { // itera por cada elemento 0,1,2..
    $ins->bindParam(1,$fecha);
    $ins->bindParam(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    //$ins->bindParam(':Total', $total,PDO :: PARAM_STR);
    $ins->execute(); // ejecutar el INSERT
}
```

Puedes usar la opcion de decodificar en formato de array (`json_decode(data, as_array=true)` si te resulta mas comodo:

```
 $array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true); // notar 2do parametro
 var_dump($array); // un array con 1 elemento 'data'
 $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas(fecha, dinero) VALUES (? , ?)"); // solo 2 valores: fecha, dinero
 $res = false;
 foreach ($array["data"] as $index=>$value) {
    $ins->bindParam(1,$fecha);
    $ins->bindParam(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    //$ins->bindParam(':Total', $total,PDO :: PARAM_STR);
    $ins->execute(); // ejecutar el INSERT
}
```

Comment: cual es la diferencia de los ejemplos que pusiste? por que me da error los dos

Comment: si pongo el primero me manda a mi echo de error y si pongo el segundo da error en el foreach

Comment: AJuste ambos ejemplos corrrigiendo el SQL INSERT y agregando `$ins->execute()`, y corregi el segundo json_decode (faltaba un 2do parametro `true`) .  Si te sigue dando error puedes indicar que salida tiene el var_dump para confirmar el formato del json.